# Angular 14 not able to create components

Tags: angular

Upgrade app to v14.0.2 but when I try to create new component, it throw following error.

```
ng g c views/multi-select
Project "undefined" does not exist.
```

following is my angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/data.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "sweetalert2",
              "file-saver",
              "rxjs",
              "angular2-datatable",
              "moment-timezone"
            ],
            "aot": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/style.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "node_modules/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, we can pass the `--project xyz` to get past the error. [Reference](https://angular.io/cli/generate). Eg: `ng g c <path> --project xyz --module kkk`

Comment: `--project xyz` did not resolve the issue. Instead, I have to update `angular.json`.  I changed the value of `"root"` from `""` to `"src"` (my project's root folder) like `> "$schema": ...., "version": ...,  "newProjectRoot":...., "Project": { "<Your Project Name>":{"root":"",...`.  
  After `$ ng g c <component name>`, I received msg `More than one module matches. Use the '--skip-import' option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specify a module.` Then I ran `$ ng g c <componet name> --skip-import`. It ran successfully. That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look **changes** at **angular.json**, seems property **defaultProject** needed for it (by default upgrade remove this property)

Comment: working with following warning ````DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory.````

Comment: great that i can help)

Comment: I don't understand it. Mine has output "Nothing to be done" when typing "ng generate component about"

Comment: in case you don't want to change angular.json you can use the command 
ng g c src/app/AppYouNameComponent --project projectName

Answer (score 1):

After checking my **angular.json** if found out I'm missing this property

```
{
    ...
    "defaultProject": "attendance",
    ...
}
```

for your issue that **attendance** will be your **project-name**